# Can my compiler be configured to error if an include path doesn't exist? (GCC, MSVC)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-c++

To catch technical debt, I would like the compiler to throw an error if one of the include paths does not exist.  Is this possible with either GCC or MSVC?

Comment: Some compilers might have an option to warn about such things, but I wouldn't  expect to be able to check with every C or C++ compiler.   You would have better chance with configuring your build script (e.g. Makefile, IDE configuration file, etc) to check relevant paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does [`-Wmissing-include-dirs` command line switch for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) suit your needs? For making the compiler generate error, replace `-W` with `-Werror`, i.e. `-Werror=missing-include-dirs`

https://godbolt.org/z/f7cvbKjcP